# how to pass another argument to url django?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views, python-requests-html

dans my views.py of page1.html :

```
def spwords(request, spray_id)     
  if request.method == 'POST':
    value= request.POST["rangeVal"]  #### the other argument that i want to pass it to views.py of the second page html ...
    form = forms.SpwordsForm(request.POST)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sp_url', args=[sp_id]))  # if POST we go to page2.html on this url
```

in my url.py :

```
 url(r'^queries/(.*)$', qviews.sp_queries, name='sp_url')
```

in my views.py of the Page2.html :

```
 def sp_queries(request, sp_id):
      #### here i want to recupere arguments : sp_id and value
```

i want to pass  value= request.POST["rangeVal"]  of the views.py of the first page html to the second page html, i.e , i want to pass value in arguments of "HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sp_url', args=[sp_id]))".

but i want to keep the format of urls.py : i.e just   queries/sp_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use url querystring. For example:

```
url = "{}?rangeVal={}".format(reverse('sp_url', args=[sp_id]),value)
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Here I am adding the value of rangeVal as url querystring and passing to HttpResponse. Now to get the value in `sp_queries`, you can use the following code:

```
def sp_queries(request, sp_id):
    value = request.GET.get('rangeVal', None)
```

### Alternative solution:

Use `request.session`. For example:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    value= request.POST["rangeVal"]
    form = forms.SprayKeywordsForm(request.POST)
    request.session['rangeVal'] = value
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('sp_url', args=[sp_id]))

def sp_queries(request, sp_id):
    value = request.session.pop('rangeVal', None)
```

For more information, please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: thank you very much , but i dont change the format of url ,i want to keep only query/sp_id without ?rangeVal , because if we do this , we must change all the request after , in page3.html